# in visual studio 2012, when i open an existing web site project, it causes a full recompile of the web site. why? and how do i stop this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, webforms

specs:
windows server 2008
visual studio 2012 premium
website hosted in IIS 7

website is compiled and running fine. I can browse it from IE. but If I then open the web site in visual studio, it recompiles my site. this site is rather large and takes about 15 minutes to recompile. how do I stop visual studio from doing this.

Comment: Normally your site should have it's solution and project somewhere else, and be *deployed* to IIS. That helps to avoid this kind of problem. If you aren't doing it, you probably don't have any kind of version control, which is also rather bad.

Comment: I'm confused, are you opening the solution in Visual Studio from the _server_? If so, that's a pretty bad practice and you should have a local version that you are publishing when changes are made.

Comment: I am opening a "web site" from a local iis server. this is not to be confused with a traditional "web application" project. 1. file > open web site 2. IIS 3. choose a website from the list of IIS Sites.

Comment: This issue did not occur when the same website was configured in a windows server 2003 / IIS6 environment. I do not control the installation and configuration of this environment. It is handled by another team.

Comment: My only workaround at the moment, when doing a "file > open website", is to select "File System" instead of "Local IIS".

Comment: @Magus, MS supports the web site project which allows one to connect directly to a local or remote IIS and work directly with the files. This has been around for years, but for unknown reasons behaves differently in my newly upgraded environment. Also, please do not assume our organization does not use version control, that's not nice.

Comment: @dgarbacz do you mean a production web server? Then the answer is no, we do not open production web sites in visual studio. Our development and testing environment consists of a vast array of windows server virtual machines.